# SQL server table population source

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have an Audit database(created by someone else).

Something is polulating it, with table sizes data (which makes sense as it is Audit database).

The SQL server has too many jobs.

I want to know what is populating the audit tables.

Is there anything like sys.comments etc? which can tell me what is populating tables or do I have to check the code inside each job?

Regards

Manjot

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? SQL Server 2008 has built-in support for auditing. Triggers are used most often for auditing-- have you checked them?

Comment: It is:


Microsoft SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.818 (X86)

Comment: I've added a SQl Server 2000 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at msdb..sysjobsteps in the command column for the destination table names; this will only work if they are using T-SQL to populate the tables.  If they're using an SSIS (or DTS) package, this won't work.

Comment: OK, did you look in syscomments and find nothing as well?  If so that rules out triggers, and my suggestion ruled out sql steps in jobs.  That leaves (AFAIK) binary steps in jobs (DTS packages on SQL 2000) OR an application outside of SQL Server.  You could look at sysjobsteps where subsystem <> 'TSQL' and start working your way through the packages.

Answer (score 1):

you could try running something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%YourTableName%'
    ORDER BY 2,1
```

**EDIT** after OP mentioned SQL Server 2000

this should work on SQl Server 2000:

```
--remove comments to see the actual text too
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name --,c1.colid,c1.text
    FROM sysobjects                  o
        INNER JOIN syscomments      c1 ON o.id = c1.id
        --join to next section of code in case search value is split over two rows
        LEFT OUTER JOIN syscomments c2 ON o.id = c2.id AND c2.colid=c1.colid+1
    WHERE c1.text Like '%YourTableName%'
        OR RIGHT(c1.text,100)+LEFT(c2.text,100) Like '%YourTableName%'
    ORDER BY 1--,2
```

Comment: It tried it but it is complaining about sys.sql_modules. I have SQL 2000, should this work on it?

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is being populated by triggers onteh the audited tables.

Comment: it is getting populated by a stored procedure which is being called from somewhere...... dont know where.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what causes data to go into the audit table, you can run a (very) brief Profiler session against the database, filtering specifically on that table, while triggering the action.  That will give you further steps to back-trace the root action.